# Why java.se module isn't loaded?

Tags: java, module, java-17, java-module

I use Java 17 and I am trying to load all Java SE modules (**not** JDK).

The code I try:

```java
AtomicInteger y = new AtomicInteger();
ModuleLayer.boot().modules().stream()
        .map(Module::getName)
        .sorted()
        .filter(x -> x.startsWith("ja") && !x.equals("java.smartcardio"))
        .forEach(x -> System.out.println("#" + y.incrementAndGet() + " | " + x));
```

The predicates inside the `filter` help me keep *only* the Java SE modules (which `java.se` belongs in as we see here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/index.html). But even If I remove them, the module is not returned.

I see the `java.se` module in the filesystem (inside `lib/src.zip/...` and `legal/java.se`). It even exists in the ExternalLibraries of my IDE (Intellij):

[image]

The output of the code:

[image]

Comment: How did you run this program?  Did the command-line include `--add-modules=java.se`?

Comment: I tried with JShell, and with the module explicitly added it does show up in the end result. Perhaps the reason is because `java.se` is only a container module - it's created to easily be able to include all the Java SE modules.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341158/why-is-add-modules-necessary-for-modules-which-are-on-the-module-path) and its references shall help you relate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m assuming that you are running your code as part of a non-modular (classpath) application, as otherwise the module’s `requires` directive(s) would control which modules are present.

The policy for such applications has changed with Java 11. In previous versions, the `java.se` module was used as root module for non-modular applications if it existed.

[`java.lang.module` documentation of Java 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/module/package-summary.html#:%7E:text=the%20readability%20graph.-,Root%20modules,-The%20set%20of):

> The set of root modules at compile-time is usually the set of modules being compiled. At run-time, the set of root modules is usually the application module specified to the 'java' launcher. When compiling code in the unnamed module, or at run-time when the main application class is loaded from the class path, then the default set of root modules is implementation specific (*In the JDK implementation it is the module "java.se", if observable, and every observable module that exports an API*).

[`java.lang.module` documentation of Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/package-summary.html#:%7E:text=the%20readability%20graph.-,Root%20modules,-The%20set%20of):

> The set of root modules at compile-time is usually the set of modules being compiled. At run-time, the set of root modules is usually the application module specified to the 'java' launcher. When compiling code in the unnamed module, or at run-time when the main application class is loaded from the class path, then the default set of root modules is implementation specific. In the JDK the default set of root modules contains *every module that is observable on the upgrade module path or among the system modules, and that exports at least one package without qualification*.

<sup>(Emphasis added by me in either citation)</sup>

This new policy excludes `java.se` itself because it does not “export[s] at least one package”.

Compare with [JDK-8205169](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8205169):

> This [old] policy is problematic when creating a run-time image that contains `java.se` and also contains a java.* module that is not in Java SE but exports an API, e.g. `java.json`. When compiling or running non-modular code, a developer needs to specify `--add-modules` to ensure that the non-Java SE java.* modules in the run-time image are resolved.
>
> A second point is that the original policy was created to ensure that the `java.corba` and Java EE modules (that existed in Java SE 9 and 10) were not resolved by default. These modules are proposed to be dropped from Java SE 11 so this aspect of the policy is no longer relevant.

> Change the policy so that the default set of root modules is simply all observable modules on the upgrade module path or among the system modules that exports at least one package, without qualification.